# DAM Connector - How to implement user management and restrict the folders for users / groups

Tags: sdl-tridion, adam-connector

We integrated DAM in SDL-Tridion using a DAM connector. Now the requirement is, we would like to restrict the DAM folders for users / groups in tridion.

Do you have any suggestions about how to implement the user management in Tridion to put some restrictions on the DAM folders?

Thank You

Comment: My ECL knowledge is very rusty... but wouldn't Tridion permissions set on the stub folders apply?

Comment: Hi @NunoLinhares,

No, I don't see security tabs from where we can set permissions. It's missed in this and this is what we want to implement.

Thank You

Comment: If you don’t get an answer here, I’d advise you to contact customer support. This seems like a valid use case to me.

Comment: Are you trying to restrict the visibility of select items from the DAM for all Tridion Sites users or is this about specific sets of external DAM content for different users? Everything from the mount point is represented by a single stub Schema, so Tridion Sites authorization (permissions) give you all-or-nothing visibility per ECL provider. I'll offer some approaches, but it really depends on what you're trying to restrict.

Answer (score 1):

To separate what ECL items the CMS users can see or select, consider these options depending on your use case.

### Hide certain DAM items from all CMS users

If your use case is that the DAM has items that CMS users should not see or use, then don't expose those items through the ECL provider. That may be done programmatically in the ECL provider code or through however the DAM handles access for the configured ECL (system) user.

### Control permissions on the *linking* items

Ultimately, CMS users will select ECL items from a linking Component or Page. Here you could restrict access on the linking items using:

- Permissions on the folders of the linking Components
- Permissions on the Structure groups of the linking Pages
- Optionally, permissions on the folder containing Schemas you want to restrict

By removing read on the folder containing select Schemas, users won't be able to create or edit Components based on those Schemas.

### Separate DAM into separate ECL providers

Finally, if you have a use case that different sets of DAM items should be used by different Schemas, perhaps separate ECL providers to the same DAM might help. For example, you might separate images from videos and handle these through different ECL providers. See [@Bart's answer to another ECL question](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/1407/46) for some context.